# When executing second for loop into listbox program populates no data

Tags: c#

so the assignment is to read from the student file into an array and read into the answer key array, compare the two and output a grade based on the array comparison.
the issue i'm having is that when i try to load the answer key into it's array it's like its not even getting the data, because all the questions output as wrong.
below is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AshleyBrown_CPT185A01S_Chapter7Lab
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //variables
        private const int SIZE = 20; //current # of q's on test
        private int index = 0, count = 1; //counter variables
        private int wrong = 0, right = 0; //grade variables
```

these are the arrays that are used for the answers:

```
        //arrays
        private char[] studentAnswers = new char[SIZE];
        private char[] answerKey = new char[SIZE];


        private void calculateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //prevents any file errors
            try
            {
                ReadStudentFile();
                ReadAnswerKey();
                CompareAnswers();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File doesn't exist or has the wrong name.");
            }

        }

        private void clearBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Clear Form
            studentAListBox.Items.Clear();
            correctAListBox.Items.Clear();
            wrongAListBox.Items.Clear();
            incorrectBox.Text = "";
            correctBox.Text = "";
            percentBox.Text = "";

        }

        private void exitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //close program
            Close();
        }
```

method for reading the student file that works:

```
        private void ReadStudentFile()
        {
            //Stream Reader Setup
            StreamReader studentFile;
            studentFile = File.OpenText("C:\\Users\\aabro\\Documents\\_CPT 185\\AshleyBrown_CPT185A01S_Chapter7Lab\\Student File.txt");

            //Read Student Answers into studentAnswers Array
            while (index < studentAnswers.Length && !studentFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                studentAnswers[index] = char.Parse(studentFile.ReadLine());
                index++;
            }

            //Close Student Answer file
            studentFile.Close();

            //Display Student Answers
            foreach (char answer in studentAnswers)
            {
                studentAListBox.Items.Add(count + ". " + answer.ToString());
                count++;
            }
        }
```

method for reading answer key that populates with no data:

```
        private void ReadAnswerKey()
        {
            //Stream Reader Setup
            StreamReader answerFile;
            answerFile = File.OpenText("C:\\Users\\aabro\\Documents\\_CPT 185\\AshleyBrown_CPT185A01S_Chapter7Lab\\Answer Key.txt");

            //Read Answer Key in answerKey Array
            while (index < answerKey.Length && !answerFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                answerKey[index] = char.Parse(answerFile.ReadLine());
                index++;
            }

            //Close answer key file
            answerFile.Close();

            //clear count
            count = 1;

            //display answer key in correct answer list box
            foreach (char key in answerKey)
            {
                correctAListBox.Items.Add(count + ". " + key.ToString());
                count++;
            }
        }

        private void CompareAnswers()
        {
            //reset count
            count = 1;

            for (index = 0; index < answerKey.Length; index++)
            {
                //determine if answer is right
                if (studentAnswers[index] != answerKey[index])
                {
                    wrongAListBox.Items.Add(count + ". " + answerKey[index]);

                    wrong++;
                    count++;
                }
            }

            //fail display
            if (wrong > 5)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Student has failed");
            }

            //calculations
            double pointPerQ = 5;
            double wrongTotal = wrong;
            double wrongPointTotal = wrong * pointPerQ;
            double grade = 100 - wrongPointTotal;

            //output grade information
            incorrectBox.Text = wrong.ToString();
            correctBox.Text = right.ToString();
            percentBox.Text = grade.ToString("p0");
        }
    }    
}
```

this is the current output from running the program, I did double check the file names and contents as well.

[output of current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCN9o.png)

Comment: I've tried various loops with some not even being entered so i'm really desperate on where i'm going wrong here.

Comment: disregard the foreach loop in the answer key section, that's the first piece of code i tried that populated empty data into the listbox

Comment: _"disregard the foreach loop in the answer key section"_ You can Edit your Question and remove parts of it if you want: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74075639/edit

Comment: You can use [local variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables) in your methods. This is maybe a problem because you are always incrementing `index` in `while loop`.

Comment: I'm not sure how to mark solved but Lazar you were right thank you!

Comment: You could answer your own question if @LazarĐorđević does not: https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=stackoverflow%20self%20answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue that I saw in code is using of `index` in multiple `while loops` without previously assigning to 0.
I suggest using of [local variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables)(variable which exists only in the current block of code).

Also in my opinion it will be good to declare and initialize new variable in `for-loop` like this:

```cs
for(int index = 0; index < answerKey.Length; index++) 
{
  // your code
}
```

it will be more readable and easier if you want later to separate loops in methods or move in service or helper.